# Rails 3.1 Generating Stylesheets attached to ActiveRecord Model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, asset-pipeline, assets

What we used to do in Rails 3.0 was have paperclip attach a file to our 'Site' model that represented css stylesheets. We have tons of sites in our application each with a stylesheet that gets generated everytime attributes in the site like site.color1 or site.color 2 change.
Then we have a .sass file that uses variables like $color1 and these are interpreted to generate the correct css file and upload it with paperclip

Here's the relevant part of Site.rb (model):

```
has_attached_file :stylesheet, PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS

def generate_site_specific_stylesheet(force = false)
  if use_custom_stylesheet && (force || color_changed?)
      stylesheets_path = Rails.root + 'app/assets/stylesheets'
      template = File.read(stylesheets_path + '_site_specific_stylesheet.sass')
      sass_engine = Sass::Engine.new(template, :load_paths =>[stylesheets_path.to_s, '.'],
                                 :template_location => stylesheets_path.to_s, :custom =>            {:site => self})
      stylesheet_contents = sass_engine.render
      puts stylesheet_contents
      self.stylesheet = StringIO.new stylesheet_contents
      self.stylesheet.instance_write(:file_name, 'site_stylesheet.css')
      self.stylesheet.instance_write(:content_type, 'text/css')
  end
  true
end
```

The issue right is that when these stylesheets are getting created they are not recognizing sass helpers like image-path. I have not been able to find a workaround for this. We do have custom sass functions defined in a module (module Sass::Script::Functions) but the helpers don't work in there either and I can't figure out how to use the image_path method in include ActionView::Helpers, though I've tried including that module to my sass functions module with no luck.

Anybody have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

`image-path` helper is not affiliated with SASS. It is a method, [provided](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0d7d3a6e77c7f2f34236459bd1170951ded91bd5/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L274) my Rails itself. Try including the following module in your model class:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
```